# Logcat shows messages of system and other applications but not my application?

Tags: android, logcat

I have a LG Optimus 4x HD and I'm trying to run my android application on it.
the problem is that the logcat doesn't show any of my log messages although it shows messages of other apps as well as the system messages.
I selected my device from the DDMS Perspective, enabled debugging mode on my device, don't have any filters in my logcat, tried verbose, error, ...

Comment: which flavor of logs are you using in your code? e, d, w...

Comment: I tried them all still no log message appears

Comment: what if you close Eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using), any emulator instance running and attach your device only to USB and in a console/terminal you enter: adb kill-server, then adb devices (so adb will be restarted and you should see your device listed) and then adb logcat. You should see logs, so then launch your application from the device (not reopening the IDE).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I tried what you suggested and got a lot of log messages that i can't figure out whether the log messages of my application are there or not  and i got this messages only in the cmd how can i get them in my eclipse window as well

Comment: Thanks alot fasteque everything is just working very good.
I just restarted eclipse and i got all the stuff working at once
Now, I can accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to restart your IDE (Eclipse or whatever you're using).

If it does not work, please try:

- close Eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using), any emulator instance running
- attach your device only to USB
- in a console/terminal you enter: `adb kill-server`, then `adb devices` (so adb will be restarted and you should see your device listed) and then `adb logcat`.

You should see logs, so then launch your application from the device (not reopening the IDE).

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem. If you're using Android Studio pay attention to select the application you want to debug in logcat's panel. Otherwise it will show all the things about your phone

This part :
[image]